# 403 forbidden when encoded + (%2B) used in PHP GET request

Tags: javascript

This is a strange one. I seem to be getting a **403 Forbidden error** when I include a string that contains a double quote followed by a + symbol in a GET request.

Variables:

```
var iname = 'Chevalier de Fleur';

var itemdescription = '"Fleur Synchron" + 1 or more non-Tuner monsters
Once during each of your turns, when your opponent activates a Spell/Trap Card, you can negate the activation and destroy that card.';
```

I am passing a request as follows

```
jQuery.getJSON('https://example.org/myphpfile.php?itemname=' + iname + '&itemdesc=' + encodeURIComponent(itemdescription) + '&callback=?',
                            function (values) {
```

This works perfectly for almost all of my 9000+ items that get checked except for this one. When the URL above is passed in, I get a **403 forbidden error**.

I think I've narrowed it down to the encoding on the + sign.

The request ends up looking like this:

```
https://example.org/myphpfile.php?name=Chevalier%20de%20Fleur&desc=%22Fleur%20Synchron%22%20%2B%201%20or%20more%20non-Tuner%20monsters%0AOnce%20during%20each%20of%20your%20turns%2C%20when%20your%20opponent%20activates%20a%20SpellTrap%20Card%2C%20you%20can%20negate%20the%20activation%20and%20destroy%20that%20card.
```

On this segment of it:

```
&desc=%22Fleur%20Synchron%22%20%2B%20
```

If I remove the %2B which is for the + symbol then it works perfectly. I thought it may have had something got to do with having a double quote **"** followed by a **+** but I have more items that do this and none seem to replicate this behavior.

I've currently fixed it by removing with it replace (I really don't need the + anyway):

```
itemdescription.replace('+', '' );
```

So while it is working currently, I'm still curious and would really like to learn **WHY** it didn't work as I'm sure I'm probably doing something wrong.

Server info:

Apache 2.4.34
PHP 5.6.36

Comment: I think we need some more information on your stack: apache, nginx, framework used. They may affect the behaviour of the request and response and may be configured to respond accordingly to the url given. knowing those it might be possible to narrow down the problem. That's not a problem or PHP alone.

Comment: Heya, using Apache 2.4.34. I'm also on a shared hosting server, not sure if that matters.

Comment: Is there a way you can get us your virtual host config added to the question?

Comment: All code you're showing us is Javascript while the only tag you have is PHP? What does the receiving end look like? I have a hard time seeing that having %2B would make any difference unless the PHP code returns a 403 for some reason. Show us the PHP code as well. Also, try and just have something like `die('test')` in the top of the PHP file and check if you still get a 403.

Comment: I'd have to ask my hosting if I can get a look at it. I'll email them and post back the details if they allow it. Also, wasn't sure what to tag it as, I guessed since it's a GET request for a PHP file that I'd mark it as php.

Comment: Now that I think about it, would the PHP Code/File even matter? It's not being allowed to even contact the file as it's getting: You don't have permission to access /myphpfile.php on this server.

Comment: It depends. If you do `http_response_code(403); exit;` in PHP, you would get the same response, so it _could_ be the PHP that returns that response.

Comment: I tried die('test') but I didn't seem to do anything. Could it be my header on the php file causing it I wonder: header('Content-Type: application/javascript; charset=utf-8');